Does the "identity" permission trigger a warning in a chrome extension?
I've added the "identity" permission to my extension to implement a "Continue with Google" feature, but I'm unsure if it will trigger a new warning. If it does, my extension will be disabled for all users until they manually re-enable it by accepting the new permission, which I want to avoid.
I tried using Extension Update Testing Tool by Google, which is supposed to show what permission warnings are generated. It didn't show any new warnings after I added the "identity" permission. But the developer documentation states that this permission does generate a warning, specifically "Know your email address".
Screenshot of the relevant section in the documentation
Has anyone worked with this permission? Does it indeed produce a warning?
Also, I don't want to put this permission into "optional_permissions" because Firefox doesn't allow it there. Handling this differently on Chrome and Firefox would complicate the codebase, and I'd like to avoid that.

It's a bug in the documentation (they copypasted description from identity.email), you can report it at the bottom of the page.

I thought so too, but I really need to be sure.

The testing tool shows the real thing.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
